# Count per category on seperate columns - Panda Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe with 3 columns:

```
Brand     Model          car_age

PEUGEOT   207            4. 6-8
BMW       3ER REIHE      2. 1-2
FIAT      FIAT DOBLO     3. 3-5
PEUGEOT   207            1. 0
BMW       3ER REIHE      2. 1-2
PEUGEOT   308            2. 1-2
BMW       520D           2. 1-2
...       ...            ...
```

And I want to group by **Brand** and  **Model** and calculate the count per `car_age` category:

```
Brand    Model      "1. 0" "2. 1-2" "3. 3-5" "4. 6-8"

PEUGEOT  207         1        0        0        1
PEUGEOT  308         0        1        0        0
BMW      3ER REIHE   0        2        0        0
BMW      520D        0        1        0        0
FIAT     FIAT DOBLO  0        0        1        0
```

PS: `1. 0` means category one that corresponds to car age of zero. `2. 1-2` means category two that corresponds to car ages between 1-2. I enumerate my categories so they appear in the correct order.

I tried that:

```
output_count = pd.DataFrame({'Count':df.groupby('Brand','Model','car_age').size()})
```

but it dropped an error:

> ValueError: No axis named Model for object type <class
> 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Could anyone help me with this issue?

I think I provided enough information, but let me know if I can provide more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab([df['Brand'], df['Model']], df['car_age']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
car_age    Brand       Model  1. 0  2. 1-2  3. 3-5  4. 6-8
0            BMW   3ER REIHE     0       2       0       0
1            BMW        520D     0       1       0       0
2           FIAT  FIAT DOBLO     0       0       1       0
3        PEUGEOT         207     1       0       0       1
4        PEUGEOT         308     0       1       0       0
```

Comment: how do I remove the first column ? `car_age`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to group by a data-frame with multiple columns is to use square brace around the columns name

```
df.groupby(['Brand','Model','car_age'])
```

I hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can call. If you want to see how it works granularly

```
def group_by(df):
    data_dumm = pd.get_dummies(df['car_age'])
    data =df.drop(columns='car_age')
    X= pd.concat([data,data_dumm], axis=1).groupby(['Brand','Model']).sum()
    return X.reset_index()
group_by(df)
```

output:

```
    Brand   Model       1. 0    2. 1-2  3. 3-5  4. 6-8
0   BMW     3ER REIHE   0       2       0       0
1   BMW     520D        0       1       0       0
2   FIAT    FIAT DOBLO  0       0       1       0
3   PEUGEOT 207         1       0       0       1
4   PEUGEOT 308         0       1       0       0
```